# use mysql_ instead of mysqli_ in wamp server

Tags: php, mysql

i have a working code with `mysql_` statement now i am running it on WAMP server it always give error Deprecated: `mysql_`, i can not change hundred of files , any work around to work with mysql statement at this point ??

Comment: That's one of the reasons, why you usually abstract the DB access in your application, so that in case of an update or change of underlying system, you do not have to change hundreds of files, but just your abstraction.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/i-think-my-post-wasnt-received-well-because-i-made-grammatical-mistakes-what-c/291370#291370) little guide could serve maybe as a little step to formulate your questions more clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can turn off deprecated errors in `php.ini`. Just find the `error_reporting` and change it to this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

And don't forget to restart the server to see changes.